# VerifyError: Verifier rejected class com.salesforce.marketingcloud.config.a

Tags: marketing-cloud, sfdcmobilesdk-android

I bumped version from SFMCSdk Android (8.0.5) to  SFMCSdk Android (8.0.8) and started seeing this error message in my emulators on firebase cloud. I also see the same error locally on my emulators.

Reverting the version back to 8.0.5, the error disappears.

```
void com.salesforce.marketingcloud.config.a.b(org.json.JSONObject) failed to verify: void com.salesforce.marketingcloud.config.a.b(org.json.JSONObject): [0x88] expected to be within a catch-all for an instruction where a monitor is held (declaration of 'com.salesforce.marketingcloud.config.a' appears in /data/app/SOMEPACKAGE_NAME-tAXMR4iM7iDFj9srjDwCJw==/base.apk!classes36.dex)
at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.MarketingCloudSdk.a(Unknown Source:336)                                                                                                    at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.MarketingCloudSdk.a(Unknown Source:80)
```

Comment: Open a support case.

Comment: Any resolution for this? We started getting this error after upgrading to Gradle 7.6.0 and AGP 7.3.1. and we are using SFMC 8.0.7.

Comment: We have the same problem and Salesforce is already working to solve it
https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000iwAkxAAE/android-app-crashes-on-during-initialization-with-marketingcloudsdk-versions-807-or-808

Comment: 8.0.9 was released a couple of weeks ago. This issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in the ART compiler that is affecting some versions of Gradle/Android Studio/et al. when integrating our SDK (ref. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37012699#comment13)

We do, in fact, have some methods which have a `try-catch` block around a `synchronized` block of code.

Problem Code (`Public Service Announcement`)

```kotlin
try {
  synchronized(lock) {
    // some code
  }
} catch (e: Exception) {
  // handle error
}
```

This has been "fixed" and will be released with Android SDK version 8.0.9. The tentative date for this release is tomorrow, May 9, 2023, but please know that release schedules can slip.

The new code is ...

```kotlin
synchronized(lock) {
  try {
    // some code
  } catch (e: Exception) {
    // handle error
  }
}
```

Yes. The issue is that ridiculous. We had 3 customers report this problem, but we have dozens (maybe even North of 100) of customers that are working fine with the 8.0.8 release. *sigh*